# Regex for inserting space after different characters

Tags: python, regex, string

Would like to add a space in between different characters. The one I have now adds it in-between every character, whereas I would like to omit that if the characters are the same (consecutive).

```
import re
string = "CEEEETTEEEEGGGCCBCTTBHHHHHCCEEEEEEEEETTEETT"
space = re.compile(r"(?<!^)(?=[CEHBGITS])(?!$)")
print(space.sub("\1", string))
```

Expected result is: `C EEEE TT EEEE GGG CC B C TT B HHHHH CC EEEEEEEEE TT EE TT`

Comment: Expected result is ```C EEEE TT EEEE GGG CC B C TT B HHHHH CC EEEEEEEEE TT EE TT ```

Comment: Why do you insert `"\1"`?

Comment: To match character for substitution, perhaps so?

Comment: Thanks for the green checkmark but I think it's a bit early for that as you don't want to discourage other answers. May I suggest you retract the checkmark for now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=(.))(?!\1)(?=.)', ' ', str)
```

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKRIwVZB3dkVCEJCQKS7u7uzs5NzSIiTBwg4g6VcYfIhIepATUAtRal6xaVJGkXqGvY2thp6mpoa9ooxhkDSVk9TXUdBXQFIAA3X5OIqKMrMK9Eo1uT6/x8A) <sup><sub><-</sub></sup><sub>\(ツ)/</sub><sup><sub>-></sub></sup> [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0TqBsX/1)

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
(?<=(.)) # positive lookbehind asserts that the current string location
         # is preceded by a character that is saved to capture group 1
(?!\1)   # negative lookahead asserts that the current string
         # location is not followed by the content of capture group 1
(?=.)    # positive lookahead asserts that current string location
         # is followed by a character
```

The current string location can be thought of as a position between consecutive characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to match the consecutive character using a capture group and a backreference, and in the replacement use the full match denoted by `\g<0>` predeced by a space.

To prevent a leading space, you can assert that there is at least a preceding character.

```
(?<=[CEHBGITS])([CEHBGITS])\1*
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly of left the current position is

  - `[CEHBGITS]` Match 1 of the lister characters
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `([CEHBGITS])` Capture **group 1**, match 1 of the listed characters
- `\1*` Optionally repeat what is captured in group 1 using a backreference

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8TF0KF/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/g5LKS9).

For example

```
import re
s = "CEEEETTEEEEGGGCCBCTTBHHHHHCCEEEEEEEEETTEETT"
pattern = r"(?<=[CEHBGITS])([CEHBGITS])\1*"
print(re.sub(pattern, " \g<0>", s))
```

Output

```
C EEEE TT EEEE GGG CC B C TT B HHHHH CC EEEEEEEEE TT EE TT
```

---

A shorter version matching non whitespace characters:

```
(?<=\S)(\S)\1*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NL1zG2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(.)(?=(?!\1).)', r'\1 ', text, flags=re.S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qExUdZ/1). *Details*:

- `(.)` - Capturing group 1 (its value is referred to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern): any one char
- `(?=(?!\1).)` - a positive lookahead that requires any single char (`.`) that is not the same as the char inside Group 1 (`(?!\1)`) immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OzveU9):

```py
import re
text = "CEEEETTEEEEGGGCCBCTTBHHHHHCCEEEEEEEEETTEETT"
print( re.sub(r'(.)(?=(?!\1).)', r'\1 ', text, flags=re.S) )
# => C EEEE TT EEEE GGG CC B C TT B HHHHH CC EEEEEEEEE TT EE TT
```